# Post by Email - Shortcode for Language?

Tags: posts, email

I really like the idea of being able to publish new blog posts through an easy email.

However i'm missing one feature, or i haven't been able to find it.
Is it possible to define a language of the new blog post through a shortcode aswell?

I'm using Jetpack and Polylang.

Thank you!

Regards,
Leeooh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to get Jetpack and Polylang to properly work together when it comes to pushing posts by mail into the desired language category.

But, i have found a plugin that offers that called Postie.
The Polylang addon costs 29$. http://postieplugin.com/